# Code review? Is there a way to write this better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have some code.

```
$(this).find('.change--button__approve').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $(thisChange).attr('data-type', 'approved').attr('data-changeRule', 'once');
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('p').attr('class','approved').addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.changeStatus').text('approved for this document');
    }
  });
  $(this).find('.change--button__approveAlways').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $(thisChange).attr('data-type', 'approved').attr('data-changeRule', 'always');
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('p').attr('class','approved').addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.changeStatus').text('approved for every document');
    }
  });;
  $(this).find('.change--button__reject').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $(thisChange).attr('data-type', 'rejected').attr('data-changeRule', 'once');
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('p').attr('class','rejected').addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.changeStatus').text('rejected for this document');
    }
  });;
  $(this).find('.change--button__rejectAlways').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $(thisChange).attr('data-type', 'rejected').attr('data-changeRule', 'always');
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('p').attr('class','rejected').addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.changeStatus').text('rejected for every document');
    }
  });;
```

Because of the repetitive nature of the code, I figured there must be a better way to write this. I'm still a js beginner so I'd love to know how to write this cleaner/better.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange ;)

Comment: Nice! I'll post future requests over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an optimized code :

```
var _this = $(this);

_this.find('.change--button__approve').click(function() {
  var sibling, _this = $(this);

  if (_this.hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
  } else {
    $(thisChange).attr('data-type', 'approved').attr('data-changeRule', 'once');
    sibling = _this.parent().parent().next();
    sibling.find('p').attr('class','approved').addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
    sibling.find('.changeStatus').text('approved for this document');
  }
});

_this.find('.change--button__approveAlways').click(function() {
  var sibling, _this = $(this);

  if (_this.hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
  } else {
    $(thisChange).attr('data-type', 'approved').attr('data-changeRule', 'always');
    sibling = _this.parent().parent().next();
    sibling.find('p').attr('class','approved').addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
    sibling.find('.changeStatus').text('approved for every document');
  }
});

_this.find('.change--button__reject').click(function() {
  var sibling, _this = $(this);

  if (_this.hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
  } else {
    $(thisChange).attr('data-type', 'rejected').attr('data-changeRule', 'once');
    sibling = _this.parent().parent().next();
    sibling.find('p').attr('class','rejected').addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
    sibling.find('.changeStatus').text('rejected for this document');
  }
});

_this.find('.change--button__rejectAlways').click(function() {
  var sibling, _this = $(this);

  if (_this.hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
  } else {
    $(thisChange).attr('data-type', 'rejected').attr('data-changeRule', 'always');
    // Store into a variable to optimize execution speed
    sibling = _this.parent().parent().next();
    sibling.find('p').attr('class','rejected').addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
    sibling.find('.changeStatus').text('rejected for every document');
  }
});
```

As you see, the main problem is the using of $(this).parent().parent().next() on two simultaneous lines, which cause speed issue. By storing it in a local variable, this function chain is not runned two times, and the local variable is deleted after usage.

The second problem (less important) is the repetitive usage of $(this) which needs to create a jQuery instance each time you use it. By storing it in a local variable `_this` you can use at as often as you want without causing a instanciation that takes time.

**EDIT :** Another more complex but better way is this one :

```
var _this = $(this);

var details = {
  'approve': ['once', 'approved', 'approved for this document'],
  'approveAlways': ['always', 'approved', 'approved for every document'],
  'reject': ['once', 'rejected', 'rejected for this document'],
  'rejectAlways': ['always', 'rejected', 'rejected for every document']
}, keys = Object.keys(details);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
  // Create a lambda function to use local variable 'scope'
  (function(scope) {
    // Here is the content of 'scope' :
    // scope[0] : value of 'data-changeRule' ('once' or 'always')
    // scope[1] : value of 'data-type' and 'class' ('approved' or 'rejected')
    // scope[2] : message to display 'approved for this document'...
    _this.find('.change--button__' + scope[3]).click(function() {
      var sibling, _this = $(this);

      if (_this.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
      } else {
        $(thisChange).attr('data-type', scope[1]).attr('data-changeRule', scope[0]);
        sibling = _this.parent().parent().next();
        sibling.find('p').attr('class', scope[1]).addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
        sibling.find('.changeStatus').text(scope[2]);
      }
    });
  }).call(this, details[keys[i]].concat([keys[i]])); // Call the lambda function with its informations
```

Please note that this code is not optimized as best I can but if I optimize it it will be ugly.

**EDIT 2 :** This is, I think, the faster and better way to do your stuff :

```
var _this = $(this),
    keys = ['approve', 'approveAlways', 'reject', 'rejectAlways'];

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
  // Create a lambda function to use local variable 'scope'
  (function(name) {
    _this.find('.change--button__' + name).click(function() {
      var sibling, _this = $(this),
          approve = (name.indexOf('approve') !== -1 ? 'approved' : 'rejected'), // Is the button an approving or rejecting button ?
          always  = (name.indexOf('Always') !== -1); // Is the button setting always or only for THIS document ?

      if (_this.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
      } else {
        $(thisChange).attr('data-type', approve).attr('data-changeRule', (always ? 'always' : 'once'));
        sibling = _this.parent().parent().next();
        sibling.find('p').attr('class', approve).addTemporaryClass('bounceIn', 500);
        sibling.find('.changeStatus').text(approve + ' for ' + (always ? 'every' : 'this') + ' document');
      }
    });
  }).call(this, keys[i]); // Call the lambda function with its informations
```

Only a few strings are stored and your function `_this.find('.change--button__...').click(` is writed one time only and runned by the loop multiple times. If you want to add buttons, you can simply add their name in the array `keys`.

I hope I helped you :)

Comment: Getting rid of the brackets for single line if statements is a matter of preference. Just because it's possible doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: You're right, but it permit to have a cleaner code (I think)

Comment: Again, that is personal preference. I wouldn't bring it up in a code review because it's not objectively correct. I think it's more comfortable to read with the brackets.

Comment: Ok I'll remove that

Comment: You most certainly did help me! I now understand the guy who said that almost all of his work is done by posting to StackOverflow. My only follow up question (so far) is why did you choose to use "lambda function" instead of "anonymous function"? Is there a difference?

Comment: A lambda function is defined into a function, like here. An anymous function doesn't have a name, like here. So this function is lambda AND anonymous.

Comment: Sorry, @ClementNerma, one more question. Can you explain this in plain English:

`(name.indexOf('approve') !== -1 ? 'approved' : 'rejected')`

Comment: This is a ternary condition : if the condition `name.indexOf('approve') !== -1` is true, will return `'approved'`, else will return `'rejected'`. The condition search the 'approve' term in the name, so if it found it, it will return 'approved', else 'rejected'. Do you understand ?

Answer (score -1):

try storing your strings

```
'.change--button__approve', '.change--button__approveAlways',...
```

in an array like

```
var strings = new Array('.change--button__approve', '.change--button__approveAlways', '.change--button__reject','.change--button__rejectAlways');
```

and use a for-loop to avoid code duplication:

```
for(int i=0; i<strings.length;i++){
    $(this).find(strings[i]).click(function(){
        ... 
    }
}
```

your changing string 'once'/'always' also need an array if this basically works
(not completely sure)